# Utilizing The 'find' Utility - Wrong Pattern?

Tags: find

I've been trying to find a particular shared object within ./lib/ using the 'find' utility in the bash shell. To be more specific, to find this shared object I wanted to find all files that started with 'lib'. Here's a list, for example.

```
libpango-1.0.so.0  
libpango-1.0.so.0.3600.8 
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.3600.8
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.3600.8
libpangoxft-1.0.so.0
libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.3600.8
```

I tried using the -name option with the pattern 'lib.*', but none of the results I was looking for came up. Rather, several files from different directories & subdirectories were printed, whatnot. To be more specific, I typed this into the terminal:

```
find . -name 'lib.*' -print
```

Where exactly did I go wrong? What can I do to improve my pattern?

On another note, I'm using bash.

Comment: Try `find . -name 'lib*'` instead.

Comment: To elaborate a little, the argument to `-name` is a shell pattern, not a regular expression.

Comment: Still no results, unfortunately. I tried on another terminal, and got the same result - nothing at all. :( Even tried different variations, such as:   find . -name 'lib.*', find . -name 'lib.*', and find . -name '^lib.*' to no avail.

Comment: Do you really mean `./lib/` (a `lib` directory below the current directory, `.`) - or are you trying to search `/lib/` or perhaps `/usr/lib/`?

Comment: Ah, you'll have to pardon me, I'm still a bit new to this... just any files that contain the characters 'lib' at the beginning of the file's name. Such as libpango-1.0.so.0.

Comment: `find ./lib -name 'lib*'` or regex: `find ./lib -regex '^lib.*'`. If you are searching elsewhere, replace `./lib` to path to the diretory you are searching for.

Comment: Oh! Awesome! Thank you, @Arthur2e5! And thank you to the others that answered too. @garyjohn I will also check out shell patterns and such. :)

Answer (score 2):

You try to use a regex in your find command. To use a regex, you need the parameter `-regex` or you could use `awk` and `find` to find all files that started with `lib`.

```
find /usr/lib -type f | awk -F'/' '$NF ~ /^lib/'
```

---

*Example*

```
$ find /usr/lib -type f | awk -F'/' '$NF ~ /^lib/'
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libhousekeeping.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libkeyboard.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libxrdb.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libbackground.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libkeybindings.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libmedia-keys.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libclipboard.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libmouse.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libmpris.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libxsettings.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/liba11y-settings.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/liba11y-keyboard.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libsound.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libxrandr.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libtyping-break.so
```

---

Or without a regex:

```
find /usr/lib -type f -name "lib*"
```

---

*Example*

```
$ find /usr/lib -name "lib*"
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libhousekeeping.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libkeyboard.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libxrdb.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libbackground.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libkeybindings.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libmedia-keys.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libclipboard.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libmouse.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libmpris.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libxsettings.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/liba11y-settings.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/liba11y-keyboard.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libsound.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libxrandr.so
/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/libtyping-break.so
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find out if a particular library is installed, you can also use rpm

```
rpm -qa | grep lib
```

The installed packages usually are in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64 (for 64 bit version). So you can also do

```
ls /usr/lib | grep lib
```

Or the find utility you were using

```
find /usr/lib -name "lib*"
```